# Number of elements of order $2$ in a group of order $10$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

Consider a group $G$ of order $10$.

Then $G$ can be abelian as well non-abelian.

What is the number of non-trivial elements of $G$ of order $2$?

**Answer:**

If $G$ is abelian, $G$ can be cyclic as well non-cyclic.

If $G$ is cyclic ,then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$,which has only $1$ element of order $2$ i.e., $\bar 5$ .

If $G$ is non-cyclic,then also it has $1$ element of order $2$.

But if $G$ be non-abelian,then the situation becomes different.

By Sylow principle, $G$ has $5$ Sylow $2$-subgroups  and hence there are $5$ elements of order $2$.

My question is-

**Edit:** How to turn the non-abelian case when the group will abelian using Sylow theorem??

In non-abelian case we get $5$ sylow $2$-subgroup. 
How this turn into $1$ sylow $2$-subgroup is $G$ becomes abelian ??

Comment: Sylow Theory is always applicable, irrespective of a group being abelian or non-abelian. Would you expect the *same* number of elements of order $2$ for these cases? If two groups have the *same* order they do not have to be isomorphic, hence they do not have the same number of elements of a given order.

Comment: There is no non-cyclic abelian group of order $10$.  But that point aside, the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups is not predicted by the Sylow Theorems to be $5$ only.  It says in your case that, if the number is $n_2$, then $n_2\equiv 1\pmod{2}$ and $n_2\mid 5$.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I'll remove my comment.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes?  The question seems to be based on a misunderstanding, but the asker has explained their reasoning, and it seems that it should be easy to give an answer that would clear it up.

Comment: @NateEldredge agreed.

Comment: @NickyHekster, how to argue turn the non-abelian case when the group will abelian using Sylow ?? In non-abelian case we get $5$ sylow $2-$subgroup. How this turn into $1$ sylow $2-$ subgroup is $G$ becomes abelian.

Comment: See the answer of Batominovski. The gist of it is that Sylow theory work everywhere but depends on the underlying group structure, for example in Abelian groups as you know all Sylow subgroups are unique, $n_p=1$ for every prime dividing the order of the group.

Comment: @NickyHekster,Yes I got the proper answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you want from your unclear question, but I hope this will ease your confusion.  I shall argue that the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups in this case is what differentiates abelian groups of order $10$ from nonabelian groups of order $10$.

Let $G$ be a group of order $10$.  Suppose that $n_p$ is the number of $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$, where $p$ is a prime natural number.  In what follows, for each positive integer $k$, $C_k$ denotes the cyclic group of order $k$.

By Sylow Theorems, $n_5\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ and $n_5\mid 2$.  Therefore, $n_5=1$ is the only possibility.  Thus, there is a unique Sylow $5$-subgroup of $G$.  This subgroup must be normal, and we shall call it $N$.  Since $|N|=5$, we have $N\cong C_5$.

Using Sylow Theorems again, $n_2\equiv 1\pmod{2}$ and $n_2\mid 5$.  This leaves two possibilities: $n_2=1$ and $n_2=5$.

If $n_2=1$, then there exists a unique Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$.  Again, this subgroup must be normal, and we shall call it $H$.  As $|H|=2$, we have $H\cong C_2$.  Since $N\cap H$ is a subgroup of $N$ and $H$, we have
$$|N\cap H|\,\Big\vert\,|N|=5\text{ and }|N\cap H|\,\Big\vert\,|H|=2\,.$$
This shows that
$$|N\cap H|\,\Big\vert\,\gcd(5,2)=1\,.$$
That is, $|N\cap H|=1$, making $N\cap H=\{1\}$, the trivial subgroup of $G$.  This shows that $N$ commutes with $H$.  (If $x\in N$ and $y\in H$, then $$xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=(xyx^{-1})y^{-1}\in H\text{ and }xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=x(yx^{-1}y^{-1})\in N\,,$$
whence $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in N\cap H=\{1\}$).  Therefore, the subgroup $\tilde{G}$ of $G$ generated by $N$ and $H$ is isomorphic to the direct product $N\times H$.  Because $N\cong C_5$ and $H\cong C_2$, we get $$\tilde{G}\cong N\times H\cong C_5\times C_2\cong C_{10}$$ is an abelian group of order $10$.  As $G$ has order $10$, it follows that $G$ is equal to $\tilde{G}$, making $G$ a cyclic group of order $10$.

Let now assume that $n_2=5$.  Suppose that the five Sylow $2$-subgroups of $G$ are $\{1,a\}$, $\{1,b\}$, $\{1,c\}$, $\{1,d\}$, and $\{1,e\}$.  Write $N=\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$ for some $x\in N$.  By the same argument as the previous paragraph, we can see that $a,b,c,d,e\notin N$.  Because $|G|=10$, we get
$$G=\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,a,b,c,d,e\}\,.$$
We shall now prove that, in this case, $G$ is nonabelian.  If $G$ were abelian, then it follows that $\{1,a\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ (every subgroup of an abelian group is normal).  However, this means $\{1,a\}$ is the only conjugate of $\{1,a\}$.  However, other Sylow $2$-subgroups of $G$ are conjugates to $\{1,a\}$, and this yields a contradiction.  Therefore, $G$ is nonabelian.

In conclusion, whether $G$ is abelian is dictated by whether $n_2=1$ or $n_2=5$.  We can in fact infer from the previous paragraph that there is a unique nonabelian group $G$ of order $10$ up to isomorphism.  This group is the dihedral group $D_5$ of order $10$.

To see the last assertion, observe that $axa^{-1}=x^k$ for some $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.  Therefore, $$x=a^2xa^{-2}=a(axa^{-1})a^{-1}=ax^ka^{-1}=(axa^{-1})^k=(x^k)^k=x^{k^2}\,.$$
Thus, $x^{k^2-1}=1$, whence $5\mid k^2-1$.  This shows that $k=1$ or $k=4$.  If $k=1$, then we can see that $G$ is abelian, which is not what we want.  If $k=4$, then $G$ is generated by $x$ and $a$ with $x^5=1$, $a^2=1$, and $axa^{-1}=x^4=x^{-1}$.  This is precisely the definition of $D_5$.

Comment: Nice and well-explained answer

Answer (score 1):

It's well known there are only two groups of order $10$.  The abelian one is cyclic, so there's one element of order $2$.

The nonabelian one is $D_5$, where there are $5$ reflections, of order two.